# Is there a way to self-host mongoose databases?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am getting started with writing an API for a project and the [tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4) I am following suggests I sign up for a hosted solution. I think that is ridiculous. My project is simple and I do not feel the need to be locked in to a service. If it helps, I am using [Express](http://expressjs.com/).

Comment: "mongoose databases" - yes, the database is called MongoDB. You can run it on any VPS.

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose is a node.js module (library) which is used to interact with a database, called MongoDB.

There are some websites like mongolab.com which offer plans for development for free, so you would jsut need to sign up and you will get a database without installink anything in your computer/server etc. This is why they say it is easier.

You can install MongoDB in your local computer to test (I think most of us have it) and use just that one for developing and testing.

To install MongoDB it all depends which Operating System you are using at the moment. But you can look up on google: "Install MongoDB MacOSX/Window/Ubuntu/etc.." and normally is just one simple command. To connect to it in your local you don't need a user or anything I guess.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation @DevAlien. I will look for ways to self-host MongoDB databases and report back here with my findings. I'm not sure why newbie SO questions are subject to drive-by downvotes so often. *Everyone* was a newbie at something at some point.